# For loop an argument

Tags: r, for-loop, arguments

I want to calculate the power of a full factorial design using the skpr and AlgDesign packages. I included my code below with a picture of the output. I want to do a for loop that iterates .1 from 0-2.5 for the effectsize argument inside the eval_design function. I want to create a table that has the parameter column and then columns of power by .1 of effectsize. I included a picture of a spreadsheet that I am trying to reproduce. Is there a way to use a for loop on an argument?

I appreciate any help.

```
library(skpr)
library(AlgDesign)

FL = expand.grid(A = as.factor(c("-1", "0", "1")), 
                 B = as.factor(c("-1", "1")), 
                 C = as.factor(c("-1", "1")))

Design = gen_design(candidateset = FL, 
                    model =~A + B + C + A:B + B:C + A:C,
                    trials = 12)

Powertable  = eval_design(design = Design, 
                          alpha = .2, 
                          effectsize = .1,  
                          detailedoutput = TRUE) 

Powertable
```

[Output of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ta19x.png)

[image]

[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rc8b6.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To do this using a loop, just replace the `effectsize` argument with the iterator like below.

```
FL = expand.grid(A = as.factor(c("-1", "0", "1")), 
                 B = as.factor(c("-1", "1")), 
                 C = as.factor(c("-1", "1")))

Design = gen_design(candidateset = FL, 
                    model =~A + B + C + A:B + B:C + A:C,
                    trials = 12)

result <- data.frame(param = rep(NA, times = 17))

for (i in seq(0, 2.5, by = 0.1)) {
  Powertable  = eval_design(design = Design, 
                            alpha = .2, 
                            effectsize = i,  
                            detailedoutput = TRUE) 
  if (all(is.na(result[, "param"]))) {
    result[, "param"] <- Powertable$parameter
  }
  result[, paste("effect", i, sep = "_")] <- Powertable$power
}

> head(result[, 1:5])
        param effect_0 effect_0.1 effect_0.2 effect_0.3
1 (Intercept)      0.2  0.2043084  0.2170947  0.2379503
2           A      0.2  0.2015984  0.2063745  0.2142712
3           B      0.2  0.2043084  0.2170947  0.2379503
4           C      0.2  0.2043084  0.2170947  0.2379503
5         A:B      0.2  0.2015984  0.2063745  0.2142712
6         B:C      0.2  0.2043084  0.2170947  0.2379503
```

Comment: This is great! I have a couple of questions. Why is times set to 17 for result? A:C is missing from the result, do you how I can fix this? Thanks

Comment: @Saucier It is set to 17 because `Powertable$power` is of length 17 (not the only way to accomplish this). The result does contain A:C, but it is in row 6 so it is not printed by `head()`.

Comment: Ok great, thank you!